# How to make a pseudo element same height and width in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-shapes

The `.speech` height may vary therefore looking for solution to make `.speech::after`'s width same as `.speech`'s height.

**ideal result**
[image]

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.speech {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.speech::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border: 3px solid deepskyblue;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, green 0%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="speech">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.</div>
```

Comment: You basically want `.speech:after` to be a square with an edge length of `.speech`'s height?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to have an increasing width of the sides of the bubble? Or is your ident to have this element be as high as the bubble parent element but have the notch always be centered vertically? So: fixed width notch with variable height?

Comment: @user3154108 I need `.speech`'s height for  `.speech:after`'s width

Comment: @NicoO the `.speech` content may vary that is why looking for such solution. Just updated the question

Comment: @user3154108 Yup, the plan is to rotate that squire and hide half part :-)

Comment: I did not ask "why" you want such a solution. That is up to you. I think you ask the wrong question, hence my update requests. It looks like you want to set the width of the bubble container accordingly to the parent height, as you want to rotate it by 45deg. There are solutions to create a "bubble" other than that. It will be easier if the width of the bubble is actually fixed. So my question is: Is the width relative to the parent height really important for your use case or do you just want to have a nice bubble effect were the width may be fixed?

Comment: There are some tricks to match the height of an Element to its width, but I seriously doubt matching the width to height can be done in pure CSS. If you want the optics, you should look into Styling Borders into shapes

Comment: @NicoO As a solution I found make squure and rotate. it is highly appreciated if you have better solution as per the image in the question :-)

Comment: @user3154108 as a solution the shape height must increase based `.speech`. Could  you please let me know if you have alternative solution

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily need pseudo elements for this, as long as you use CSS gradients, since all browsers that support gradients also support multiple backgrounds:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.speech {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient(tomato,tomato),
              linear-gradient(to top right, tomato 49%,transparent 51%),
              linear-gradient(to bottom right, tomato 49%,transparent 51%);
  background-size: calc(100% - 30px) 100%, 30px 50%, 30px 50%;
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.</div>
```

Comment: It is 2017 and I still have to get used to multiple backgrounds ;D ... Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a `clip-path` will give you the intended result.

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that defines what
>   part of an element should be displayed. Those portions that are inside
>   the region are shown, while those outside are hidden. The clipping
>   region is a path specified either as a URL referencing inline or
>   external SVG, or as a shape, such as a circle().

[clip-path - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility)

```js
var addText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.";

jQuery('.add-text').on('click', function(){
  jQuery('.alt-speech').append(addText);
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; /* for the sake of demonstration */
}

.speech {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.speech::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border: 3px solid deepskyblue;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, green 0%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* Additional */

.alt-speech {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.alt-speech:after {
    content: "";
    width: 50%;
    background: tomato;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 30% 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 30% 50%);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.add-text {
    transition: .7s;
    color: white;
    background: tomato;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add-text:hover {
    background: #c12a0f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-text">Add Text</div>

<div style="margin: 20px 0px"></div>

<div class="alt-speech">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.</div>
```

**Further Reading:**
[Creating Responsive Shapes With Clip-Path And Breaking Out Of The Box](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/creating-responsive-shapes-with-clip-path/) (Smashing Magazine)

**NOTE:**
This is an experimental technology, carefully review cross browser compatibility and support before implementing in production.

**Cross browser compatibility & support Overview:**

1. [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)
2. [clip-path - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the `clip-path` doesn't support IE11 & even Edge :-(

Answer (score 2):

This is not what you actually asked for. So please correct me if I'am wrong. You asked for a bubble that grows width the height of the parent container. This is not the case with this answer. But I feel this is the desired effect anyways.

Instead of rotating an element by 45% this is using two pseudo elements and linear backgrounds to have a bubble effect.

The width is fixed and may be set according to your needs. But the bubble itself follows the height of any dynamic content.

```css
.speech {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.speech::before,
.speech::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 50%;
}

.speech::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, tomato 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.speech::after {
  top: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, tomato 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="speech">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.</div>

<div class="speech">Very small</div>

<div class="speech">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width;" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <style>

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.speech {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.speech::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  top:0px;
  left:100%;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="speech">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minima possimus, maxime, fugit dolorum optio, tempora et doloribus doloremque ullam inventore repellendus veniam modi quasi iusto numquam amet eos! Exercitationem.</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ht = $(".speech").height();
    var ht1 = ht/2;
    $("head").append($('<style>.speech:after { border-top: '+ht1+'px solid transparent; border-bottom: '+ht1+'px solid transparent;  border-left: '+ht1+'px solid green;}</style>'));
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Answers should have an explanation.

Comment: @Ajeesh KH looking for solution in pure CSS